# Rails not finding environment variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I run `bundle exec rails c` to start the rails console, I get an error that says:

```
    erb):16:in `fetch': Cannot load 
   `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
    key not found: "DBUSER"
    Did you mean?  "USER" (KeyError)
```

HOWEVER, I do have this key set:

```
printenv | grep DBUSER
DBUSER=dbuser
```

why isnt rails seeing this key?

Comment: please give us the database_configuration.yml file so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Try to type 'spring stop' in your project path in console.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set up local environment variables I recommend using some gem that can handle this for you. The advantage with this method is that you can easily keep track of the variables that are being used in your Rails app. Also from the Dotenv Docs:

> It is not always practical to set environment variables on development machines or continuous integration servers where multiple projects are run.

You can use Dotenv or Figaro ( altough this last one seems not to be maintained anymore). 
The usage is basically the following:

1. Set up a `.env` file in your `/app` directory
2. Write up the variable names that will be used in your code or config files:
   `DBUSER=somekey`
3. Be sure to follow the load instructions detailed on the GitHub readme of those gems.
4. Run your Rails app and be sure the environment variables are working.

Comment: Nowdays I would recommend [DirEnv](https://direnv.net/) over DotEnv. DirEnv is language agnostic and does not require you to add `direnv` to the gemfile of every project. Also when using `DotEnv` you should place the `.env` file in the Rails root directory. Not `/app`.